# Waiting for a message response using Telegraf/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I would like to wait for the user to send a message, then assign the new message to a variable.

How can I wait for a message reply using Telegraf on Node.js?

```
const Telegraph = require("telegraf");
const APIKEY = 'LADLADJLDAKJLAK;LAKS;LSAKLDA,MDALJDALJLDAJLDAJLDAJDALDAJLADJ'
const bot = new Telegraph(APIKEY);
const loginMessage = `
PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL:
`;
bot.command("login", (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("You Entered Login");
    ctx.reply(loginMessage);//login message:Please Enter EMAIL
    //wait for user to send message
    //ASSIGN MESSAGE TO VARIABLE
  });

bot.launch();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Scenes](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=stage). but not just a normal scene but use WizardScene for better usage especially since you want your bot to kind of have an interview-like thing with users to get their info. To store user data use [Session](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=session). Out of the boxes its stores its data on memory I think to be able to persist your data even after restart use this [telegraf-session](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=telegraf-session).

Check out this tutorial it helped me out a lot [How to build OCR Bot](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-a-telegram-ocr-bot/)

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways:

1. Store chatID with state in any way ([session middleware](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=known-middleware), object, db), like `"123" : "login_step"` and check state of user first.
2. Use [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply): Add it to `reply_markup` of sendMessage. And check `reply_to_message` for your command

Comment: **Would you please emphasize more on your answer thanks @TAB_mk

Comment: When storing you can handle text messages and check if user on "login" step', ex.: `bot.on('text', async (ctx) => { const step = /*get step from storage*/;  if (step === 'login_step') { login(ctx.update.message.text) }})`. Same with reply. Get login from `ctx.message.update.text` and step from `ctx.message.reply_to_message` @AlwiMuhammad